# How to configure Flexible OR Immediate release for android in app updates?

Tags: android, in-app-update

For in-app updates feature in Android,
How to configure Flexible/Immediate release on Playstore?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own logic whether you want Flexible or Immediate Update as there is no such functionality in Google Play Console for now.

I found [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133299031#comment8) on Google Issue Tracker

> Soon you'll be able to specify an in-app update priority for your app
>   release, which will be made available through the in-app update API.
>   Please see this Android Developer Summit talk for more details:
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o_q6hatcIs

Comment: i guess, this is still open.  there's some update here from  google : 

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks/update , but i don't know how to use it.